# Printer Canon Pixma MP250 driver problems Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, canon

my printer Canon Pixma MP250 cannot auto connect in Ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10. I've tried to find and install drivers via Printers-Add without success. I have also tried to download drivers for amd64 in .deb but the App center refused to install it saying something is missing. The repository with official drivers [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu/dists/) does not include Wily Werewolf so I can't use it. What should I do then?

I can't go back to 14.04 or 14.10 because Wily has updated drivers for touchpad and wifi on Lenovo and they finally work now as supposed.

Comment: The last kernel update broke printing to my Canon. Roll back to the last kernel but one and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer [here](http://www.linuxslaves.com/2015/08/how-to-install-libtiff4-on-ubuntu-1504.html). The solution is to install libtiff4 in Ubuntu 15.04.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this line into the file

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe
```

and then save it. After that, install the required packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtiff4 libtiff4-dev
```

Then it is possible to add a printer through the Printers app.

#### Note:

Once the package is installed,  the repository for precise should be removed. Alternatively downloading the deb files from precise repo manually and installing can also be an option.

Comment: An alternative to adding the repository (and causing possible package conflicts) is to make a symlink to the newer library as detailed here [How do I install libtiff.so.3?](//askubuntu.com/q/44132) - this may not always work, but it's safe to try and may save you some trouble if it does fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

In **Ubuntu 20.04** the necessary libpng12-0 + libtiff4 libraries are not available in the Ubuntu repository. I installed my printer drivers by adding a ppa repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the printer + scanner drivers:

```
sudo apt install cnijfilter-mp250series 
sudo apt install scangearmp-mp250series
```

Add your printer via the "Printers" in your Desktop GUI.